# Tell a friend script not sending email php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to execute "Tell a friend" php script, but that is not sending any emails, not to admin, friends, sender. Other emails on same server working fine.

I don't understand why this is not working, as other emails pages like contact us, registration (which send confimation email) all working on same server, please help me..

Html Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span>Complete the details below to send this link to a friend:</span>
<?php 
$refurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>
<span><? print $refurl;?></span>

<form name="tellafriend" action="send_group.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkfields()">
<table>
<tr>
<td> Your name*:</td>
<td> <input name="name" size="30" maxlength="45"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Your email*:</td>
<td><input name="email" size="30" maxlength="45"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><p align="center">Enter your friend's email addresses:</p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email 1*:</td>
<td><input name="fmail1" class="bordesolid1" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email 2*:</td>
<td><input name="fmail2" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email 3*:</td>
<td><input name="fmail3" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><p align="center"><span>This message will contain your name &amp; email address.</span>
<br>
<input onClick="validate();" type="button" value="click once to send">
<input type=hidden name=refurl value="<? print $refurl;?>"> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

if(count($_POST)) {
foreach(array('fmail1','fmail2','fmail3','email','name') as $key) $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
if(!is_secure($_POST)) {
    die("Peace People! Stop Spamming!");
}

$name = $_POST[name];
$email = $_POST[email];
$fmail1 = $_POST[fmail1];
$fmail2 = $_POST[fmail2];
$fmail3 = $_POST[fmail3];
$refurl = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';


$to = "arvindsri123@yahoo.com"; 
$subject = "Recommendation form submission"; 

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n".
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = '<html><body>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">'.$name.' has used your recommendation form using an email address of '.$email.' </p>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">The people the recommendation has been submitted to are: </p>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">'.$fmail1.' </p>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">'.$fmail2.' </p>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">'.$fmail3.' </p>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">The page recommended:</p>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">'.$refurl.'</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$sentmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
// $thankyoupage = "thankyou.htm"; 
//echo $sentmail;

if($sentmail) { 

$name = $_POST[name];
$email = $_POST[email];
$fmail1 = $_POST[fmail1];
$fmail2 = $_POST[fmail2];
$fmail3 = $_POST[fmail3];
$refurl = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

$tsubject = "A web page recommendation from $_POST[name]";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n".
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = '<html><body>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">Hi, '.$name.' whose email address is $_POST[email] thought you may be interested in this web page. '.$email.' </p>';
$message.='<p style="margin-top:10px;">'.$refurl.'</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$sentmail = mail($fmail1,$fmail2,$fmail3, $tsubject $message, $headers);
echo '<h4>You have sent emails...</h4>';


//header("Location: $thankyoupage");
exit;
}
function is_secure($ar) {
$reg = "/(Content-Type|Bcc|MIME-Version|Content-Transfer-Encoding)/i";
if(!is_array($ar)) {
    return preg_match($reg,$ar);
}
$incoming = array_values_recursive($ar);
foreach($incoming as $k=>$v) if(preg_match($reg,$v)) return false;
return true;
}
function array_values_recursive($array) {
$arrayValues = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if (is_scalar($value) || is_resource($value)) {
        $arrayValues[] = $value;
        $arrayValues[] = $key;
    }
    elseif (is_array($value)) {
        $arrayValues[] = $key;
        $arrayValues = array_merge($arrayValues, array_values_recursive($value));
    }
}
return $arrayValues;
}
?>
```

I am using Bluehost web hosting, and other emails properly working as I said Contact us, Registration confirmation emails.. etc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on localhost then it won't send email.. to do so you need to host on server
Try to host on free hosting server.. it will work!

Comment: you can also send mails in localhost. Very possible!

Comment: I am testing on web server "bluehost" and Its not sending emails to any which is listed.